# SDR Output Monitor + Protection Circuit for Amplifier

Tags: pcb, amplifier, rf, buffer

I'm working on a PCB for a satellite ground station and I just had a question about the feasibility of a circuit I had come up with. The ground station uses an ettus x300 SDR and then the signal is routed to an empower RF 1094 amplifier which then goes to the antenna. We are dealing with the 135-145 MHz and 430-440 MHz bands. Because the SDR can output up to +27dBm and the amplifier can only take +10 dBm before being damaged, I wanted to design a circuit that would monitor the output power and shut down the amplifier if greater than +10dBm was applied. In addition, on the output side, I need to switch in a filter for the 430-440 band if we are transmitting at the 135-145 band because of the third-order harmonics from the amplifier. The third-order harmonics with 135 fall right in the middle of 430-440 and this particular amplifier has a third-order level of -15dBc. Harmonics have to be below -50dBc to comply with FCC regulations. So, I also wanted the circuit to automatically detect whether the SDR was transmitting on the UHF or VHF band.

To do this, I was going to make a PCB that has two SMA connectors that connect via a small microstrip transmission line. This PCB would go between the SDR and amplifier. There would then be a buffer amplifier that is connected to the microstrip line. I was considering something similar to the one found [here](https://rocelec.widen.net/view/pdf/8q2le702uc/NATLS08367-1.pdf?t.download=true&u=5oefqw). I then wanted to use a resistive splitter network to branch the output of this buffer into 3. One part would go to a filter that passes the 135-145 band, another would go to a filter that passes the 430-440 band, and one that has no filter at all. On the output of these would be an RF detection IC such as this [one](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/linear-technology/LT5581IDDB%23TRMPBF/LT5581IDDB%23TRMPBFCT-ND/1927874). I would then feed the output voltages from the IC into a microcontroller so it could read the voltages and see what actions it would need to take, either shutting down the amplifier or switching in a filter.

At a high level, am I understanding the functionality of these chips correctly? Would the circuit as I described it here work? Most of my RF experience comes from hands-on experience and I haven't taken any classes specifically for RF.

Additionally, the filter for 135-145 will reflect almost all of the power in the 430-440 band. Will this power that gets reflected back into the network affect the other two points where I am measuring the RF power? I would imagine that due to the resistive losses across the divider network, this would be negligible, but I just wanted to make sure that this was a correct assumption.

Thanks

Comment: The buffer linearity at VHF frequencies is poor for RF but OK for other things less critical. You can also consider a 9.5 dBm limiter

Comment: Hey @TonyStewartEE75 could you clarify what part of the datasheet showed the poor linearity? Is it the graphs on page 7?

Comment: I was concerned about all the ones in 4 & 5 that do not directly show  THD because they would look pretty bad with modulation. Even at 100W it's -15 dB

Answer (score 1):

https://www.minicircuits.com/pdfs/VLM-52+.pdf

Alternative [image]
9.5 dBm SMA Limiter 10 ~ 500 MHz
[image]
[image]
[image] ballpark Gaussian not ideal
[image]

It depends on all your specs how best to design it a mux'd output filter.

Comment: Hey thanks for the information. Could you clarify what the image from falstad is showing specifically? I understand the two filters below it but not what the purpose of the falstad simulated one is.
And as far as connecting the two designs you had for the filters here together on the output end of whatever buffer I use, will the resistor divider network that I mentioned work for this?


EDIT: I think I answered my own question, that's the output filter that I will need to switch in.

Comment: This 1st in an inverse Chebychev LPF with a notch on the 3rd and 5th harmonic roughly, not precisely. Don't know how group delay affects your fundamental BW.